# Is Ubuntu still installing I'm not sure using VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox and I'm trying to install Ubuntu 32 bit and after I get past the part of clicking installing and the message saying it will use the following partitions to install and I hit continue but now so far all I'm getting is the wallpaper and it has been an hour now and I don't think it has froze cause the mouse position still moves from another position on the Virtual Box screen from time to time but nothing that shows a progress bar or anything that shows status of installing.

Comment: Well, the mouse is handled at a lower level, and will often be the only thing working, when things go wrong.  I would say that there is a problem, possibly with the display settings or graphics capabilities, etc.  Does your computer run the live CD?

Comment: i'm sorry this is my first time using virtual box ever what do you mean by the live CD? I downloaded the iso file from ubuntu website

Comment: Sorry, you are correct; for some reason, I thought I had read something about a CD; I added it at the end, without checking.  If you had burned a CD, or USB thumbdrive, you could boot from that, run Ubuntu, and not write anything to the hard disk.  But on a CD, you can't save anything; on a USB drive, you could.

Answer (score 0):

You can check what is going on while installing Ubuntu, as shown below

[image]

notice in the picture above there is a terminal view. to show it you have just to click on the `loading bar` or over the writing above(in the picture Almost finished copying files)

Once you open it you can easily know what is going on your install.

Now why this happens to you, I suppose that there is some downloads such as language pack and some other packages that'll be downloaded during installation if you are connected, or you choose dowload updates while installting, this download may take some time

Answer (score 0):

maybe for someone this is usefull... some time ago i had a similar "problem": it took a really long time to install a guest OS inside VirtualBox, but it was not frozen!

i tested a few things and finally that helped:
[image]

i entered the guest settings and under storage i checked "Use host I/O cache"; after that everything worked pretty fast as expected!

BUT be sure to read the chapter [5.7. Host I/O caching](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#iocaching) of the [VirtualBox Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html) first, to know what you are doing!